# Boost Plugin choices

Tags: c++, unix, plugins, boost

I'm looking to implement a plugin architecture into our current application (Unix, C++) and have been reviewing the options (pending approval) within the Boost libraries.

Edit: I'm looking to dynamically add classes at runtime.

Boost.Plugin

Boost.Reflection

Boost.Extension

I was wondering what everyones experience/opinion is on these and other implementations.

Comment: You posted your proposed solutions for a problem you did not state. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eh. We just used `dlopen` and `dlsym` along with a pair of `extern "C" static` functions that must be defined in the dll

```
extern "C" static plugin* create( arg_pack* );
extern "C" static errno_t destroy( plugin* );
```

Have a plugin-manager look for ".dll" or ".so" files and load them into a
`map<string, pair< plugin*(*)(arg_pack*), errno_t(*)(plugin*)> >`

You can then lookup a plugin based on a name (the string above) and get it's 'constructor' or 'destructor'

see also: [gmodule](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html)

Comment: ABI/API compatibility checking?

Comment: @Vlad ABI -> `extern "C"` guarantees c-style mangling. API -> `dlsym` to load all relevant functions from the library. If any are missing then it's not a plugin and you need to discard the functions pointers and `dlclose` the library.

Comment: extern "C" guarantees mangling, but imagine that signature has changed, or whatever interface host provides has changed, and plugin expects different thing, the best bet would be to crash, but consequences could be very dramatic (i.e. bad prices coming from trading system, which makes a company bankrupt in a couple of seconds). There should be a set of decent checks making sure that whatever contract that is expected is met. This basically should be a main goal of plugin frameworks, not just wrapping dlopen...

Comment: Without reflection, you can't make guarantees on APIs they way you describe. The best you could do is pass in something like a `map< string, pair< type_info, boost::any> >` and let the callee examine this map for all of it's arguments. Of course, the callee could be maliciously taking 0 or 2 or more arguments. I guess you could specify `cdecl` convention so that the caller (your code) cleans the stack. I don't see a way to prevent the callee from futzing the stack by inserting inline asm.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. What you speak of is the current implementation, however i would like to reuse existing code rather than reinvent the wheel. I've taken a look at gmodule and found it insightful thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can not load classes at run-time as C++ is a compiled language and classes do not exist at run-time. Objects (instances of classes) do.

What you can do is load shared libraries at run-time and make them create objects of a certain interface.

Minimal plug-in implementation would define the interface of your plug-in and the interface of the factory function that is going to create objects with that interface. You are going to load the shared library at run-time, find the factory function with a certain name, and call the factory function to create an object. Then you use that object though the interface:

```
// plugin.h start
#include <memory>

struct PlugIn // interface
{
    virtual ~PlugIn() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

extern "C" {

typedef std::auto_ptr<PlugIn> PlugInFactoryFn();

// A plugin .so must export this one factory function.
std::auto_ptr<PlugIn> createPlugIn();

}
// plugin.h end

// somewhere in you application
#include "plugin.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

std::auto_ptr<PlugIn> loadPlugIn(char const* filename)
{
    void* so = dlopen(filename, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
    assert(so);
    void* factory_function = dlsym(so, "createPlugIn");
    assert(factory_function);
    return reinterpret_cast<PlugInFactoryFn*>(factory_function)();
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<PlugIn> a(loadPlugIn("a.so"));
    std::auto_ptr<PlugIn> b(loadPlugIn("b.so"));
    a->doSomething();
    b->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Now, this won't work on non-POSIX platforms, there could be heap problems when object is allocated on plugin's heap and deleted in main  applications. Not to mention API/ABI compatibility...

Comment: @Vlad: we are talking Unix here.

Comment: @Maxim: Still, you have to make sure that plugin and host are ABI compatible (i.e. same or compatible compiler etc), plus API compatible. That is why you need some higher-level stuff like Boost, and using cowboy dlopen is.. you know.

Comment: @Vlad: Depends on which compilers you'd like to support. For in-house plug-ins the above is just fine. If you'd like to support different compilers with different ABI then you need C-style OO, but this is beyond the scope of this question. The main idea here that your plug-in shared library does not need to export more than one function.

Comment: The idea is well explained. In general, multiple entry points makes no sense.